# How to disable Gmail add-on on mobile devices?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, gmail-addons

I do not want my Gmail add-on to be displayed on mobile devices. How can I disable it for mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

From the forum, it was stated that this action can't be done as per design. You can comment in [this thread](https://support.google.com/mail/forum/AAAAK7un8RUibSvw5omR8I?hl=en).

> There's no way to turn that off withing the (unmodified) Gmail UI.
>
> Please use the in-app **“Send feedback”** link to submit your
>   request/issue directly to Google.  You will not receive a response
>   from Google.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to hide the Gmail add-on on mobile devices.

Here is an example code snippet that will make something some up on web only, nothing on android:

```
function prodd(event) {
if (event.clientPlatform.toUpperCase().equals('WEB')) {
return [getClientInfo(event)]; 
} 
return [];
}
```

You need to make sure that you use a versioned deployment for this code. On HEAD deployment, it'll show an error: "No add-on data returned. This message is only shown in development mode."